# exception: "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException" , Column not found: 1054 Champ using laravel 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to Edit data, so for that, I should display it in a form.
In my table in the database, I have a primary key named `id_casting`

So I have he following code :

My script :

```
 $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){

          var id = $(this).attr('id');
         console.log(id);
           $('#form_result').html('');
          $.ajax({
          
             url:"castingss/"+id+"/edit",
           dataType:"json",
           type:"GET",
           success:function(html){
           /* $('#casting_name').val(html.data.casting_name);
            $('#casting_cin').val(html.data.casting_cin);
             $('#casting_email').val(html.data.casting_email);
            $('#casting_phone').val(html.data.casting_phone);
             $('#casting_age').val(html.data.casting_age);
            $('#casting_sexe').val(html.data.casting_sexe);
             $('#casting_city').val(html.data.casting_city);
            $('#casting_address').val(html.data.casting_address);
            $('#store_image').html("<img src={{ URL::to('/') }}/castingimages/" + html.data.casting_photo + " width='100' class='center'  />");
            $('#store_image').append("<input type='hidden' name='hidden_image' value='"+html.data.casting_photo+"' />");
            $('#hidden_id').val(html.data.id);
            $('.modal-title').text("Edit New Record");
            $('#action_button').val("Edit");
            $('#action').val("Edit");*/
            $('#formModal').modal('show');
           }
          })
         });
```

My Controller :

```
public function edit($id_casting)
   
 {
         if(request()->ajax())
        {
            $data = Casting::findOrFail($id_casting);
            return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
        }
}
```

My model :

```
class Casting extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
   
     protected $fillable = ["id_casting",
        "nom", "prenom" , "cine" , "date_naissance","lieu_naissance" ,"mineur","id_representant","id_type_facturation","artiste","fonction","id_type_casting ","tel1","tel2","email","photo","qualification","adresse","ville","pays"
    ];
}
```

My route :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','role:admin']], function() { 
    Route::get('/castingss/{id_casting}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\CastingController::class, 'edit']);
});
```

When I execute my code I get in console the id_casting , but I get :

```
exception: "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException"
file: "D:\\Projet_Cast_Infl\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php"
line: 678
message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'castings.id' inconnu dans where clause (SQL: select * from `castings` where `castings`.`id` = 6 limit 1)"
trace: [{file: "D:\Projet_Cast_Infl\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php",…},…]
```

i dont understand why it gives me this error when I have no primary key with name `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default laravel thinks that id is the primary key in your table. To fix this you would have to a primary key variable in your model

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id_casting';
```

You can read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys